# Jackson XML Deserialize multiple XML tag to a single Object without any error in java DTO

Tags: java, json, xml, jaxb

I have a xml like

```
<root>
  <element>
    <a>it should be single</a>
    <a>but here I am showing multiple</a>
  <element>
  <element>
    <a>it should be single</a>
  <element>
</root>
```

My java POJOs are:

```
     class Root {
       @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
       @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element")
       List<Element> element;
     }

    class Element {
       @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "a")
       String a; // Here A is not in list type
    }
```

when I send the XML as a payload of my REST API, It successfully mapped without any error, and I evaluate the data of 1st element I am only getting the second A string(i.e: but here I am showing multiple).

As I have defined in Element class that A should be a String not a list of strings but it still mapped it. Can I restrict A as a single occurrence by java code?
Note: There is a restriction I can't change A as a list of strings in class Elemnt.